# What game with numbered hairstyle options is this?

Tags: game-identification

I've seen shots of this game going around and I was wondering if anybody knew what this game is called?

Source: https://weheartit.com/entry/349621974

[image: Multiple hairstyles in a grid]

Comment: This doesn't look like a game. It looks like one of the many "doll maker" sites popular in the early 2000's. The hair is quite reminiscent of one I used back then as a teen.

Comment: Do you have anything else to go on? I mean, maybe Gaia Online? Thats the most popular of these kind of customizers that I can think of, but we cant see a lot of the menu to compare.

Comment: I was going to ask you for a better picture, but I see that you may have took it from someones account (I dont remember the website. It was a social media account though). Please let me know if you can find a better one. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This is not actually a game but a doll maker. This is an old type of Internet content where you could personalize a doll character with hair, clothes and accessories. This particular one is called [Candybar](http://elouai.com/candybar5/dress-up-girls.php).

[image]

Comment: HOW did you find this? Also, congrats! ... I guess you might've just known of it?

Comment: I looked up doll maker games with similar faces to the one the asker shared and ended up finding a similar doll editor after some digging. Then it was just a matter of finding the same page!